# How to integrate ADP employee data in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, integration, adp

I need to sync Employee data from ADP to my intranet page which is in wordpress.
Can anyone let me know the plugin or any thirdparty tool to integrate ADP employee data in Wordpress page? Pls help.

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck? See [ask] and give a [mcve] please.

Comment: Am building a intranet website using wordpress. I need to list the Employees data in a webpage where people can come and search for employee name, team etc. In order to achieve that i have to sync the ADP employee data in a webpage, I heard that there are third party tools available which will integrate employee data from ADP to Wordpress. Can you able to get this?